# Training a neural net without labels in Reinforcement Learning

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-networks

I am trying to dig further into machine learning and I am making a program to play a game as a start. I have created a game that is based on the mobile game *Flappy Bird* and can be generalized to the following:

- Actions $A = \{\text{no action}, \text{tap}\}$
- States $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $s \in S$,

  - $s_1$ is the horizontal distance to the center of the nearest forward gap
  - $s_2$ is the vertical distance to the center of the nearest forward gap
  - $s_3$ is the vertical velocity ($\text{unit}/\text{sec}$)

As a starting point, I have implemented a naive Q-Learning algorithm with positive rewards whenever it passes through a gap successfully. Everything went well and the q-table ($f(s): S \to A$) was adjusted accordingly to the rewards.

Now I would like to train a neural net to do the same. One problem that existed with the Q-Learning approach is that the algorithm does not take locality into account. I had to also discretize the feature space into very huge chunks which is not optimal. I am hoping that a neural net can solve these issues.

I am familiar with performing basic classifications with neural nets, and so I am trying to approach this problem similarly. I would just take a *state* (a vector of three real numbers) as input and an *action* as output (one neuron per action and take the one with the highest probability). The problem is, I do not have labels for training! The only thing that I get from the game is reward.

Is a neural net a good choice for this type of problem? How should I train or design such network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is DQN: Deep Q-Network.

You want to have a look at the [example code](https://github.com/MartinThoma/algorithms/blob/master/ML/rl/dqn_agent.py), but the idea is as follows:

- **Input**: The observation
- **Output**: Reward - the action can either be in the input or better one reward-prediction per possible action, if the action is discrete.

For final states, you know the true reward. Hence your target is clear (see [line 112](https://github.com/MartinThoma/algorithms/blob/master/ML/rl/dqn_agent.py#L112)). But if this is not the case, you need to adjust the target to the observed reward and the discounted expected reward ([line 113ff](https://github.com/MartinThoma/algorithms/blob/master/ML/rl/dqn_agent.py#L113-L115)).

Extremely important: **The output layers activation function**. Don't use softmax, as it is unlikely that your rewards sum up to 1. Don't use ReLU if the reward can be negtive. Simply using a linear output makes most sense in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of reinforcement learning is that it gives you a way to train a machine learning algorithm, without having labels for training.  It provides a way to obtain labels; then you use some existing ML method to build a policy.  You can use any ML method you like, including a neural network -- neural networks are often chosen for this purpose, because they seem to work well in many situations.

So, I suggest that the best answer to your question is going to be: use reinforcement learning with neural networks.  See, e.g., https://karpathy.github.io/2016/05/31/rl/ for an overview of how you could do that.

See also [Are neural networks a type of reinforcement learning or are they different?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/58131/755) for an overview of the relationship between reinforcement learning, supervised learning, and neural networks.

Comment: The links you provided are great resources, thanks!